# How to plot custom gate labels in Qiskit?

Tags: programming, qiskit

How can I create a custom gate in qiskit that is plotted using latex formatting (or another type of formatting)? For example the following code generates a circuit diagram

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
from qiskit.circuit import Gate

qc = QuantumCircuit(1, 1)
qc.append(Gate(name=r'X_t', num_qubits=1, params=[]), [0])
qc.measure([0, ], [0,])
qc.draw(output='latex', interactive=False, filename='test.png')
```

The custom gate is labelled as X_t, but I want the name to be formatted as an X with subscript t. I tried variations as

```
qc.append(Gate(name=r'$X_t$', num_qubits=1, params=[]), [0])
```

but that does not work.

Note: reported on github as well https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/3171

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to stem from the `utf8tolatex` parsing in the `pylatexenc.latexencode` package, [line 370 here](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/visualization/latex.py).  Use of this function is not yet depreciated, but it is [discouraged](https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/latexencode/#pylatexenc.latexencode.utf8tolatex), and it has the unfortunate behavior of escaping the underscore, changing `'X_t'` to `'X{\\_}t'` (this is already inserted into the latex source in a math environment, so no need for `$...$`).  A flag to disable this parsing and pass the string directly to `\\gate{%s}` would be very nice.

Also the mpl plots have a style dict kwarg structure, so that you can arbitrarily change the default name mapping with a JSON style sheet. Unfortunately, the latex plots ignore these style sheets and the mapping is hardcoded, [e.g. line 384](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/blob/master/qiskit/visualization/latex.py).

As far as I can tell, right now there's no way to accomplish what you want without running off your own branch.  That is, unless anybody knows a trick to get `utf8tolatex` to stop escaping the underscore.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to have the latex drawer do the subscript currently. As ChainedSymmetry pointed out the use of pylatexenc prevents that because it will escape or convert the underscore and symbols to their latex equivalents. This was added because when we first added custom gates support to the drawer people had issues with passing things like `custom_gate` to the drawer it would make the 'g' a subscript (see https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/2246 ). While I still think this is a sane default for people, I agree we probably should add a flag to disable the conversion to the draw() functions, so I quickly wrote up a patch for that here:

https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/3172

That being said the `mpl` drawer should work fine in the meantime for your second example with the label `name=r'$X_t$'`. That should tell matplotlib to use math mode when rendering the gates name and use a subscript.

Comment: An alternative approach to the original PR was decided on. https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/pull/3224 will solve this now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is currently possible with Qiskit, could you please add this as an `Enhancement` to the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra)? This is done by creating an `Issue` and then selecting that it is an `Enhancement`.