# How to plot custom labels for quantum registers in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming

How can I plot custom labels for specific qubits on the left and right side similar to the picture shown here (A, B, Sum ...):

[image]

Comment: See related, but possibly outdated responses here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/8329/8623

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A partial answer.**

How to customize the labels of `QuantumRegister`s:

```
from qiskit import *

red_qubit = QuantumRegister(1,'red')
blue_qubit = QuantumRegister(1, 'blue')
green_qubit = QuantumRegister(2, 'green')

circuit = QuantumCircuit(red_qubit, blue_qubit, green_qubit)

circuit.h(red_qubit[0])
circuit.x(blue_qubit[0])
circuit.x(green_qubit[0])
circuit.cx(red_qubit[0], blue_qubit[0])
circuit.cx(red_qubit[0], green_qubit[0])
circuit.cx(red_qubit[0], green_qubit[1])

%matplotlib inline
circuit.draw(output="mpl")
```

The output:

[image]